# jQuery Toggle is allowing no content

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I am working on toggling three divs based on a menu of three links.

It's working great, except I want to avoid having no div displaying.  In other words, there should always be one div displayed.  Right now if you click on a menu item twice, the div goes away completely.

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/sf23103/raervcLj/5/

HTML:

```
<a id="menu1" class="menu" data-item="#directory_default">Default</a> | 
<a id="menu2" class="menu" data-item="#directory_alpha_first_name">First Name</a> | 
<a id="menu3" class="menu" data-item="#directory_alpha_last_name">Last Name</a>

<div id="directory_default" style="">Default Content goes here.....</div>
<div id="directory_alpha_first_name" style="display: none;">First Name content goes here....</div>
<div id="directory_alpha_last_name" style="display: none;">last name content goes here....</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').click(function () {
        var $clicked = $(this)
        $('.menu').each(function(){
            var $menu = $(this);
            if (!$menu.is($clicked))
            {
                $($menu.attr('data-item')).hide();
            }
        });
        $($clicked.attr('data-item')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are hiding everything not clicked, then toggling the one that is clicked. So if the one that is clicked is already shown, toggling it will hide it.

Replace

```
if (!$menu.is($clicked))
{
    $($menu.attr('data-item')).hide();
}
```

With

```
$($menu.attr('data-item')).hide();
```

This way you will hide everything, and then will always toggle on only the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reduce your code to just

```js
$('.menu').click(function() {
  $('[id^="directory_"]').hide()
  $($(this).data('item')).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="menu1" class="menu" data-item="#directory_default">Default</a> |
<a id="menu2" class="menu" data-item="#directory_alpha_first_name">First Name</a> |
<a id="menu3" class="menu" data-item="#directory_alpha_last_name">Last Name</a>

<div id="directory_default" style="">Default Content goes here.....</div>
<div id="directory_alpha_first_name" style="display: none;">First Name content goes here....</div>
<div id="directory_alpha_last_name" style="display: none;">last name content goes here....</div>
```

On a click, hide all the divs that begins with `directory_` then show the one with the corresponding ID based on the data attribute.